# Filter Split Form data sheet By Using Combo Box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have one table that has purchases of material from several vendors, some as many as 50 to 100 items per vendor. I'm trying to use a split form with a combo box to select a vendor then show all records of the purchases from that vendor.

I listed the vendors in the combo box and tried a VBA code to filter the records

```
 Private sub cboVendors_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter= "[Vendors] = " & char(34) & Me.cboVendors &  char(34)
    Me.FilterOn =True
        End Sub
```

I'm using Access 2016 and get a:
                   compile error
                   Sub or function not defined
If I dim char(34)
I get a syntax error :

(missing Operator) in query expression[vendors] = Ace Hardware

The vendor selected.
The code I used, I found on a Youtube video online that seemed to work with Access 2007.
I'm expecting to get the results of the records pertaining to the vendor I select from the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *char* but *Chr*. However, try:

```
Me.Filter = "[Vendors] = '" & Me.cboVendors & "'"
```